# How to use elasticsearch in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a body of POST request in Java to look like this:

```
{
    "query":{
      "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "and":[
          {"terms":{"primaryType":["container"]}} , {"terms":{"LifeCycleState":["project"]}}
        ]
      },
      "query":{"match_all":{}}
    }
    },
    "aggs": {
            "status":{ "terms": {"field":"container:status"} }
         }
}
```

So far this is what I have got:

```
final FilterBuilder primaryTypeFilter = FilterBuilders.termsFilter("primaryType", "container");
final FilterBuilder lifeCycleStateFilter = FilterBuilders.termsFilter("LifeCycleState" , "project");
```

Which brought me this:

```
"terms":{"primaryType":["container"]}
"terms":{"LifeCycleState":["project"]}
```

I don't know how to move forward from here, how to wrap the terms with "and", "filtered", "query" and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of elasticsearch. I'd recommend to upgrade.

From 5.0, you must use a `bool` query which has a `filter` part. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html#java-query-dsl-bool-query

Something like:

```
QueryBuilder qb = boolQuery()
    .filter(termQuery("primaryType", "container")    
    .filter(termQuery("LifeCycleState" , "project"));
```